# Debugging ElasticSearch boolean queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm faced with an issue with an automatically-generated elasticSearch query. When running it, six of the seven shards I'm using on the index return a success, and the seventh returns this error:

```
index: "shard"
reason: "ClassCastException[
  org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2.compiler.BlankLiteral cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean]"
shard: 1
status: 500
successful: 6
total: 7
```

How can I figure out what this is coming from, considering that the explain endpoint yields absolutely nothing due to the root query being a `bool`?

The query is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "filtered": {
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "lte": "2014-05-21T21:59:59+00:00",
                  "gte": "2013-01-23T23:00:00+00:00"
                }
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "not": {
                "terms": {
                  "idCountry": [
                    "9999"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filtered": {
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "reports",
                "query": {
                  "terms": {
                    "reports.36317.flag": [
                      "o"
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "reports",
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "reports.36317"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "idTone": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].idTone.empty ? _source.idLanguage : _source.reports[reportId].idTone",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].tags.empty ? 'none' : _source.reports[reportId].tags",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    },
    "flag": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].flag.empty ? 'O' : _source.reports[reportId].flag",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    },
    "synthesioRank": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].synthesioRank.empty || _source.reports[reportId].synthesioRank == null ? '0' : _source.reports[reportId].synthesioRank",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    },
    "idUserEngagement": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].idUserEngagement == null ? '0' : _source.reports[reportId].idUserEngagement",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    },
    "idStatus": {
      "script": "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].idStatus == null ? '0' : _source.reports[reportId].idStatus",
      "params": {
        "reportId": "36317"
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "access",
    "content",
    "title",
    "date",
    "geo",
    "idItem",
    "idSiteType",
    "idSite",
    "idSource",
    "idSourceType",
    "idTopic",
    "media",
    "url",
    "idLanguage",
    "idDocument",
    "idCountry"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrown exception has to do with mvel, the scripting language used for the script_fields in your case.

The fact that only 1 shard fails maybe means that the execution of one of your scripted fields fails against one specific document in that shard.

You could try and remove those fields, one by one, along with any filter requesting that field, to spot the one that fails.

Note : the Explain API is designed to help understand scoring computation inside a sorted query. It won't help you in any way regarding a failing query.